# How to read the values when exception throwing in @FeignClient service

Tags: java, rest, kotlin, spring-cloud-feign

I receive an error when I try to call rest endpoint. I need to read the ID value returned in the error message.

Below is my code snippet that call the Rest Service and get the error in the catch block.

```
var resp: Response = try {
                        feignClient.processReservation(
                            ref,
                            request.toMessage,
                            credentials.headers()
                        )
                    } catch (ex: Exception) {
                        logger.error("msg > " + ex.message)
                    }
```

Below is the values printing in the catch block.

```
msg > [402 Service Required] during [POST] to [https://api.test.service/reserve/7c81e-9ea2-4a36-bf58-f08f/cancel] [myClient#processCancel(String,CancelRequest,Map)]: [{"error":{"code":"ALTERNATE-Booking”,”message":"Transaction declined by the user”,”details":["The booking was declined by the processing service.”,”There is already the maximum number of bookings under this service.”]},”id”:”dbb8f-1a68-46af-9sbb-f3a79d4f","liveMode":false}]
```

I want to grab the ID value from the above error message. Is there a way to read the values other than reading this whole string and identify the id ?